# How to make `i_ctrl-o` unaffected by the mode from which we entered insert mode?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode

By default, `C-o` allows to execute a normal command from insert mode. Example:

```
foo bar| baz
       ^ represents the cursor
```

The current mode being insert mode, and the cursor being after the word `bar`, to delete the next word, you could hit `C-o daw`.

However there are several ways to enter insert mode. Most of the time (`i`, `a`, `o`, `O`, ...), `C-o` will behave as expected. However, if you enter insert mode from visual mode, for example by pressing `A` from visual block mode (`:h v_b_A`),  its behavior depends on whether you've already inserted text, and the number of times you pressed it.

Example:

```
foo bar| baz
```

If you press:

- `C-v` to enter visual block mode
- `A` to enter insert mode
- `C-o` to enter normal mode
- `daw` to delete `baz`

... `daw` is literally inserted into the buffer:

[image]

If you repeat the same sequence of keys, but this time you repeat `C-o` a 2nd time:

```
C-v A C-o C-o daw
```

`C-o` behaves as expected:

[image]

There's a third behavior which requires a multi-line text to be observed:

```
foo | baz
foo   baz
```

Suppose you want to add `bar` between the `foo` and `baz` on the 2 lines.
The cursor being between `foo` and `baz` on the 1st line, you can press:

- `C-v` to enter visual block mode
- `j` to go down one line
- `A` to enter insert mode
- `bar` to insert `bar`

If you press `Escape`, you'll get:

```
foo bar baz
foo bar baz
```

Now suppose you don't press `Escape`, because before going back to normal mode, you want to delete the next word `baz`. You could press `C-o daw`, expecting the following buffer:

```
foo bar
foo bar
```

But that's not what you'll get, instead you'll have:

```
foo daw bar baz
foo bar baz
```

What happened is that when you pressed `C-o`, Vim reinserted the text you had typed (here `bar`) at the end of each line of the visual block, and moved the cursor to the upper left corner of the block. In other words, it's as if you had pressed `Escape` then `i`.

---

`C-o` is often used in an insert mode mapping. Here's an example:

```
ino <c-x><c-k> <c-o>:exe 'setl dict='
                                    \. (&l:spelllang ==# 'en'
                                    \? '/usr/share/dict/words'
                                    \: '/usr/share/dict/ngerman')
                                    \<cr><c-x><c-k>
```

This mapping customizes the default dictionary completion `C-x C-k`.

It first checks the buffer-local value of the `'spelllang'` option. If it's `en`, then the mapping sets the buffer-local option `dict` to `/usr/share/dict/words` (dictionary for english words), otherwise to `/usr/share/dict/ngerman` (dictionary to german words). Then, it performs the usual dictionary completion.

It works as long as you've entered insert mode from normal mode. But if you entered insert mode from visual mode, instead of completing the text looking into a dictionary, it dumps the `{rhs}` of the mapping inside the buffer.

Because of this, I never use `C-o` in a mapping because I don't know how to detect what was the previous mode, before insert mode.

Instead I use `C-r =`:

```
ino <c-x><c-k> <c-r>=<sid>set_dict()<cr><c-x><c-k>

fu! s:set_dict() abort
    exe 'setl dict='.(&l:spelllang ==# 'en' ? '/usr/share/dict/words' : '/usr/share/dict/ngerman')
    return ''
endfu
```

---

This solves the issue for a mapping. But in an interactive use, sometimes you have to hit `C-o` once, and sometimes twice.

Is it possible to make `i_C-o` unaffected by the mode from which we entered insert mode?

Comment: Lost you at "... daw is literally inserted into the buffer."  That is, I cannot reproduce this.  daw works as expected for me.  Are you sure you don't have a plugin conflict somewhere?

Comment: @Mass I don't think it's caused by a plugin conflict, because I can reproduce without them, by starting Vim with a minimum of initializations (`vim -Nu NONE`). I added a gif to illustrate.

Comment: Odd.  What vim version?  I did the same experiment as you and one thing I notice different is that `-- INSERT --` should change to `-- (insert) --` to indicate you are in normal mode falling back to insert mode.  I am on version 8.987.

Comment: @Mass I'm using vim version 8.0, patches `1-134` included. I think you're right, the problem seems to be fixed in recent Vim version. I've just compiled the latest version from the github repo, and `i_Ctrl-o` seems to behave properly.

Comment: Does that resolve the remainder of your question?  If so, for completeness, I can post a quick answer regarding the vim version.  Otherwise, if there are lingering issues, I will read the rest and see what I can do.

Comment: @Mass Yes it solves my issue. If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it. But I just want to find the right commit which fixed the issue. Currently I'm trying to bisect it. If I find it, I'll edit your answer to add the info.

Comment: @Mass Ok I found it, it was fixed in patch 8.0.0282: https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/0b5c93a7f266cd8c90ea27bdaf9f7214a95d64d7 Here's the url of the relevant thread on the issue tracker: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1290

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue, [needing to use CTRL-O twice when in visual-insert mode](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1290), was fixed in patches [8.0.0282](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/0b5c93a7f266cd8c90ea27bdaf9f7214a95d64d7) and [8.0.0291](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/23fa81d2223cd9bb7c51829c48047b2976bc2d11).